# Vaadin 14 application failed to build frontend after update to npm 7.20.6

Tags: npm, webpack, vaadin, vaadin14

After npm was updated to 7.20.6 I cannot build my Vaadin app anymore.

It gives following error:

```
   Insufficient number of arguments or no entry found.

   Alternatively, run 'webpack(-cli) --help' for usage info.

   Hash: 4deef033da9d3a9fa458

   Version: webpack 4.42.0

  Time: 31ms

  Built at: 08/16/2021 5:02:34 PM

  ERROR in Entry module not found:            Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader'   in '/srv/github/***/yalsee/_work/yalsee/yalsee/frontend'
  
  ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/srv/github/***/yalsee/_work/yalsee/yalsee/frontend'
```

But I have nothing that uses/imports this babel-loader in frontend folder.

I tried with Vaadin 14.5.3 and 14.6.8

Both gave me same result.

Comment: Was there any issues with the npm install or was webpack failure the only exception?

Comment: Only webpack failure.

Comment: I could replicate this by updating to latest. The workaround works as long as you remove node_modules.

Another that would seem to work fine is to have the package-lock.json for a previous version available.

Comment: Tested the versions and it would seem like something broke in 7.20.3 as from there on the build fails. We will for now mark the broken versions as blacklisted and continue with the investigaion in ticket https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/11584

Comment: The issue should be fixed and roll out in the next release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As this issue has not come up yet we will need to investigate why NPM 7.20.6 would impact the build like this.

As a workaround you should add to the vaadin-plugin the configuration block:

```
<configuration>
  <requireHomeNodeExec>true</requireHomeNodeExec>
</configuration>
```

This forces the usage of a framework installed version that is known to work.
More documentation on the maven plugin goals can be found [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/guide/production#plugin-goals-and-goal-parameters)

Comment: I can confirm that workaround works.Kiitos/Thanks.

Comment: Also as a fix/workaround is to add to `package.json` `devDependencies` the dependency `"babel-loader": "8.2.2",`